# Why is my function returning None, but when I add a print function before it, it is executing a solution?

Tags: python, printing, return

Thanks for the comments all- I managed to get it working by adding 'return' to the one_counter() function. One follow on question if I may- do we always need to 'return' something for every function? Because I came across some other code that doesn't do this, here it is:

```
def maxSlidingWindow(nums: List[int], k: int) -> List[int]:
    d = deque()  # keep this monotonic
    
    def eat(i):
        # kick from the back all indeces of smaller numbers that came before
        while d and nums[d[-1]] <= nums[i]:  
            d.pop()
        d.append(i)
    
    def spit(i):
        # kick index out the front if still present
        if i == d[0]:  
            d.popleft()
    
    for i in range(k-1):
        # first, fill sliding window except one
        eat(i)
        
    def slide():
        # then: consume next slot -> yield max -> eject last
        for i in range(k-1, len(nums)):
            eat(i)
            yield nums[d[0]]
            spit(i-k+1)
    
    return list(slide())
```

Can someone please briefly explain when we use return and when we don't need it like in the above? Thanks!

Specifically when calling another function from within the same class- when do we need to have `'return'` and when do we not?

Comment: put return before that: permutation_poss("".join(res))

Comment: Because ```one_counter(nums)``` doesn't return anything. *See the else part*

Comment: ```return``` is used in the function only if ```res not in nums```. ```permutation_poss("".join(res))``` returns a string which you are not using

Comment: permutation_poss() will return None (implicitly) if/when permutationss is an empty iterable